# JS - how to pass function as parameter (with parameters) without invoking it

Tags: javascript

I have this method:

```
myFunction: function(a,b,c) { 
   ... 
}
```

Now, I want to pass it as parameter to another method so it can be executed inside that method:

```
...
var a = "bla";
var b = "ble";
var c = "bli";
someFunction(myFunction(a,b,c),true,"test");
```

And then inside someFunction I would like to call myFunction like:

```
someFunction: function(func,bool,str){
   func();
}
```

Is that possible?

Thanks

Comment: `someFunction(myFunction.bind(null, a, b, c), true, "test");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but you have to create a function that makes the function call, i.e. [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) (aka "curry") the function reference with the parameters:

```
someFunction(myFunction.bind(this, a, b, c), true, "test");
```

Some older browsers (e.g. IE 8) doesn't support the `bind` method, but you can do basically the same with a function expression:

```
someFunction(function() { myFunction(a, b, c); }, true, "test");
```

If you are using jQuery there is a [`$.proxy` method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) that takes care of making it browser independent:

```
someFunction($.proxy(myFunction, this, a, b, c), true, "test");
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible in JavaScript.

```
someFunction(function () {
    myFunction(a,b,c);
}, true, "test");
```

You can even do:

```
var myFunc = function () {
    myFunction(a,b,c);
};
someFunction(myFunc, true, "test");
```